# HANA SQL: How to join to first row under a condition refering to main table

Tags: sql, hana

I will use a hypothetical example to illustrate my problem of joining two tables on which I have been stuck for quite a while now:

Each **Order** has many delivery dates and quantities:

**Order**:

```
OrderID   DeliveryID  DeliveryDate     Quantity
=======   ==========  ============     ========
1000      001         2017-01-01       10
1000      002         2017-01-08       10
1000      003         2017-01-15       10
1001      001         ....             10
```

The **received goods** are mapped to an OrderID, but not DeliveryID:

**Received**:

```
OrderID   InvoiceID   ReceivedDate   ReceivedQuantity
=======   =========   ============   ================
1000      1001        2017-01-01     10 
1000      1002        2017-01-09     09
1000      1003        2017-01-10     01
1000      1004        2017-01_15     10
```

I am now trying to join the Received table to my Order table. But since, for example, the second order is received in two seperate steps, I want to join the order to the latter received-line, since only then my order has fully arrived.

By joining normally via OrderID we would receive, with the upper example of 3 Orders and 4 Receivings, a total of 12 joined items.

So I want to solve this issue by accumulating the quantity for each OrderID and for each Delivery with respect to the Order ID, with my adjusted tables looking like this:

**Order**

```
OrderID   DeliveryID  DeliveryDate     Quantity   OrderedAccumQuant
=======   ==========  ============     ========   ================
1000      001         2017-01-01       10         10
1000      002         2017-01-08       10         20
1000      003         2017-01-15       10         30
1001      001         ....             10         10
```

**Received**:

```
OrderID   InvoiceID   ReceivedDate   ReceivedQuantity   AccumQuant
=======   =========   ============   ================   ================
1000      1001        2017-01-01     10                 10
1000      1002        2017-01-09     09                 19
1000      1003        2017-01-10     01                 20
1000      1004        2017-01_15     10                 30
```

My planned logic is now to join the Received table to the Order table with the first Received-line that has an equal or greater ReceivedAccumQuant than OrderedAccumQuant. In this example, InvoiceID 1002 is not joined since its delivered quantity is not the ordered quantity.

**Desired output:**

```
                                          Ordered                      Rec
OrderID   DelivID  DeliveryDate   Quant   AccQuant  RecDate InvoiceID  AccQu
=======   =======  ============   =====   =======   ======= =========  =====
1000      001      2017-01-01     10      10        .-01-01 1001       10
1000      002      2017-01-08     10      20        .-01-10 1003       20
1000      003      2017-01-15     10      30        .-01-15 1004       30
1001      001      ....
```

The desired output would show me within each OrderID: a match from all DeliveryIDs to an InvoiceID where the received_accumulated_quantity is >= than the ordered_accumulated_quantity

**My two approaches:**

***Memory allocation problem***

One approach was to Inner Join the Received table via a subquery and then rank() the joined table after partiioning by OrderID and DeliveryID and also having included the WHERE condition that Delivery.Cum_Quant >= Order.Cum_Quant. With the outermost WHERE condition of CUM_RANK = 1 we filter for only the first entry per DeliveryID that fulfills the condition.

This solution works well for a small part of my dataset, but this crashes as soon as I use the full dataset due to memory allocation, since many Received Items are being joined to the Order Items before being filtered by the CUM_RANK of 1. With about 5 million planned delivery dates and 5 million receiving dates and up to 100 of deliveries per OrderID the joined table becomes incredibly large :

```
SELECT 
  *
  ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Received.OrderID, Received.DeliveryID ORDER BY Received.CUM_QUANT) as CUM_RANK
FROM Orders
JOIN 
  (
  SELECT  
    *
    ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Received.OrderID ORDER BY ReceivedDate) AS Rank
    ,SUM(QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY Received.OrderID ORDER BY ReceivedDate) AS Cum_Quant
  FROM Received
  )
ON Orders.OrderID =  Delivery.OrderID
WHERE
  Received.Cum_Quant >= Order.Cum_Quant
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID, Received.Cum_Quant
)
WHERE CUM_RANK = 1;
```

My error message being the following:
    SAP DBTech JDBC: [4]: cannot allocate enough memory: please check traces for further information

Any ideas on how to approach this?

***Access to main-table problem***

My other guess was to do the comparison of Received.AccumQuant and Orders.AccumQuant within a SELECT subquery of the JOIN statement, so that we avoid the many joins being performed. But from within the JOIN statement you cannot access the Orders table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY ReceivedDate ASC) AS RowNumb
    FROM Delivery 
    WHERE 
    WHERE Orders.OrderID = Received.OrderID 
    AND Received.AccumQuant >= Orders.AccumQuant --(this point doesnt worke since we cannot access the Orders table from here)
    ) AS DeliveryRanked
  ON Orders.OrderID = Received.OrderID
```

Comment: It's not clear what question you try to answer with the SQL query. What should be the result of the query? Should it be a list of all completely fulfilled orders? Does the DeliveryID play any role in what shall be considered completed? Maybe it becomes easier to understand if you provide an example output.

Comment: Hi @LarsBr. , thanks for your reply. 
I edited the post and included a desired output.
The result should be a list of all completely fulfilled planned deliveries, with the respective DeliveryID and InvoiceID as well as the wished DeliveryDate and the actual ReceivedDate. The DeliveryID is just an Index to all planned DeliveryDates per Order. 
I hope that clarifies it?

Comment: In other words: within each OrderID, we want to match all DeliveryIDs to an InvoiceID where the received_accumulated_quantity is >= than the ordered_accumulated_quantity

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but I am not sure if I understood completely your request.

```
SELECT a.orderID,MAX(a.DeliveryDate) DeliveryDate,SUM(a.Quantity) Quantity,b.ReceivedDate,b.ReceivedQuantity
FROM Orders a,
(SELECT orderID,MAX(ReceivedDate) ReceivedDate, SUM(ReceivedQuantity) ReceivedQuantity 
FROM Received
GROUP BY orderID) b
WHERE a.OrderID = b.OrderID 
GROUP BY a.orderID,b.ReceivedDate,b.ReceivedQuantity
HAVING SUM(a.Quantity)<=b.ReceivedQuantity
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but with the SUM in the subselect, we look at the sum over all Received items per Order, and not just the accumulated items up to a certain time. Therefore the ReceivedQuantity is the same for all InvoiceIDs and we do not know which InvoiceID matches which DeliveryID

Comment: Then use Received.AccumQuant.